# Fieldset that appears while hover

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with this program:

```css
.FIRST {
        position: absolute;
    }
.SECOND {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }
#A:hover .SECOND {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>LEGEND</legend>  
  <div class='A'>
      <fieldset id="FIRST">
          FIRST
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id="SECOND">
          SECOND
      </fieldset>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I wanted my fieldset "SECOND" to appear when my mouse enters the "A" div.

What I do not understand is that the fieldset "SECOND" appears constantly even with the "display: none" and nothing happens in the Google console when I put my mouse in my block "A".

Comment: You have your ID and class selectors the wrong way around. `.` means class. `#` means ID

Comment: also - it's better practice to use lowercase letters for naming conventions. Capitals don't really make sense

Comment: in regards to `Hi` - there's no rule against that .. ?

Comment: Oh well, that's awkward because one of my teachers taught me the opposite. And.. everything works, thank you ^^

Comment: in regards to `Hi` - SO aims to be a (semi)-professional Community where developers help each other. Not a social Network, so there is no need to greet everyone in the Post with a "Hi, whatsup y'all, I wanted to ask blah blah" Just get the Question out in a nice manner, technically correct and as objective as possible. But you'll get the hang of it, when browsing through the other Questions

Comment: @Mondertime then get new teachers xD :)

Answer (score 0):

You call a class by a **.** and an id by a **#**. So it will look like this:

```css
#FIRST {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
#SECOND {
       visibility: hidden;
    }

.A:hover #SECOND {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
        <legend>LEGEND</legend>  
        <div class='A'>
            <fieldset id="FIRST">
                FIRST
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="SECOND">
                SECOND
            </fieldset>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```